# Referencing ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Core) from Class Library (.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add reference to ASP.NET Core Web Application from Class Library project (.NET Core) which will be my Unit Tests project.

I am getting error with default empty projects(File -> New Project):
[image]

I have tried to downgrade Tests project to 1.4 with no success.

Comment: Try to change `netstandard1.5` to `netcoreapp1.0` in the test project's `project.json`.

Comment: Unit Test assemblies are applications, not class libraries. @ademcaglin: is right and `netcoreapp1.0` should be used for unit and integration testing projects

Comment: @ademcaglin You are right this solve issue. If you want you can write answer so I can mark it that resolved issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`netcoreapp` is for applications(web, console and **test**), `netstandard` is for class library projects.

So, changing `netstandard1.5` to `netcoreapp1.0` in test project's `project.json` will solve your problem.